# Inertia.js + Laravel retuns a blank page on Mobile

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, npm

lately i've been developing a Laravel + React app with Inertia.js; Everything works well in my pc, and still works well when i serve to my network (192.168.x.x), but once i access the app on my mobile phone, the page is empty. A simple whitescreen. Using firefox developer edition (on android is called Firefox Nightly) and an extension called Mobile DevTools, i discovered that the layout page (which is app.blade.php) is loaded, but the components are not being rendered.

Also, on my pc, going to the network tab on the DevTools, clicking on the request which loads the page, and going to response tab, i see that, also on pc the response is blank, but the component still loads. I'm going to attach some photos, so it is more clear what i just said (excuse my english, i'm from a foreign country)

```
app.blade.php:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ auth()->check() ? json_decode(auth()->user()->settings)->lang : "en"}}" class={{ auth()->check() ? json_decode(auth()->user()->settings)->theme : "dark"}}>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title inertia>{{ env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel') }}</title>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <!-- Scripts -->
        @routes
        @viteReactRefresh
        @vite(['resources/js/app.jsx', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.jsx"])
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased bg-neutral-200 dark:bg-slate-900">
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>
```

Inertia was installed through laravel/breeze
I already tried `npm run build`, i don't have `npm run watch` as an npm command.

[image: DevTools's Network Tab]
[image: Mobile View]

Comment: Using Vite or Mix?

Comment: I'm using Vite, first i've run npm run build, then npm run dev

Comment: Well it's calling the components, would you please check the page source

Comment: The page source on the desktop is too long to paste it here, but it seems to be ok. The desktop version is ok, it loads, it works correctly. On my phone, though, as you can see on the screenshot, it just returns a blank page

Comment: Ah, I understand. Is it styling issue on mobile as it works fine on mobile.

Comment: No, it just does not return the component, it's content/logic/style. It's like the routes on laravel does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite the provided commands for Laravel, you would use the following:

If you're using Vue with Inertia.js, run this command:

```bash
php artisan inertia:install vue --ssr
```

If you're using React with Inertia.js, run this command:

```bash
php artisan inertia:install react --ssr
```

If you've already installed Inertia.js and want to start server-side rendering, run the following command:

```bash
npm run dev && php artisan serve
```

If this commond also give you black page run this command instead of the above command:

```bash
npm run build && php artisan inertia:start-ssr
```

Please note that these commands assume you have Laravel, Inertia.js, and the appropriate JavaScript framework installed and configured correctly.